# Deleting Duplicate Data & Replacing missing values in certain areas

Tags: r, excel

So I have been looking at this code which is originally an excel sheet. Once the data set is put into R Studio then I have a few issues.

First of all I changed all the blank cells into NA once I run

```
CarparkData[is.na(CarparkData)] <- 0
```

it only changes the data which was originally NA not a blank cell.

Secondly deleting duplicate data, I used the following code and nothing happened.

```
library("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
x <-CarparkData
duplicated(x)


x[duplicated(x),]
x[!duplicated(x),]
```

As I have a row for Date and Time I would like to use this as the column to delete the rows of duplicated data. As I have data which are the same but they are at different times compared to data which is the same and the date and time is the same.

And Thirdly Replacing missing Values
Some of the data has FULL written on it and I would like to home into one column and then change FULL to the number that is full in that specific car park, so changing the FULL cells in that column and not all the FULL cells.

Sample Data

```
> dput(head(CarparkData))
structure(list(Parnell = c(188L, 183L, 185L, 229L, 237L, 272L
), Ilac = c(665, 683, 694, 769, 786, 839), Jervis = c(421, 408, 
403, 417, 423, 455), Arnotts = c(340, 344, 350, 359, 359, 355
), Malboro = c(160L, 160L, 156L, 157L, 173L, 207L), Abbey = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Thomas Street` = c(173, 173, 173, 186, 189, 
198), `Christ Church` = c(77, 76, 74, 73, 83, 91), Setanta = structure(c(24L, 
23L, 23L, NA, NA, 46L), .Label = c("10", "100", "101", "102", 
"103", "104", "107", "108", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", 
"115", "120", "123", "125", "128", "129", "131", "14", "17", 
"19", "21", "24", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "34", "36", 
"39", "40", "44", "45", "47", "48", "51", "52", "53", "56", "57", 
"6", "60", "63", "66", "67", "7", "70", "72", "74", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "84", "85", "86", "89", "9", "91", "92", "93", 
"94", "96", "98", "FULL"), class = "factor"), Dawson = c(70, 
87, 83, 118, 122, 140), Trinity = c(142L, 143L, 145L, 165L, 167L, 
191L), Greenrcs = structure(c(NA, 8L, 9L, NA, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1125", 
"157", "205", "250", "262", "264", "266", "267", "270", "296", 
"305", "311", "319", "320", "324", "327", "342", "347", "350", 
"353", "364", "371", "374", "375", "378", "379", "459", "463", 
"591", "729", "754", "761", "879", "902", "903", "907", "911", 
"913", "916", "917", "922", "931", "944", "955", "974", "985", 
"FULL"), class = "factor"), Drury = c(148, 143, 147, 182, 193, 
235), `Brown Thomas` = c(230, 231, 0, 267, 272, 293), `Date & Time` = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2019-03-19 13:43:33", 
"2019-03-19 13:55:39", "2019-03-19 14:07:35", "2019-03-19 15:45:02", 
"2019-03-19 16:00:02", "2019-03-19 16:45:03", "2019-03-19 17:00:02", 
"2019-03-19 17:45:03", "2019-03-19 18:00:01", "2019-03-19 18:00:02", 
"2019-03-19 18:45:03", "2019-03-19 19:00:01", "2019-03-19 19:00:02", 
"2019-03-19 19:07:12", "2019-03-19 19:45:03", "2019-03-19 20:00:01", 
"2019-03-19 20:00:02", "2019-03-19 20:45:03", "2019-03-19 21:00:01", 
"2019-03-19 21:00:03", "2019-03-19 21:45:04", "2019-03-19 22:00:01", 
"2019-03-19 22:00:03", "2019-03-19 22:45:04", "2019-03-19 23:00:01", 
"2019-03-19 23:00:02", "2019-03-19 23:00:03", "2019-03-19 23:45:04", 
"2019-03-20 00:00:01", "2019-03-20 00:00:02", "2019-03-20 00:00:03", 
"2019-03-20 00:45:04", "2019-03-20 01:00:01", "2019-03-20 01:00:02", 
"2019-03-20 01:00:03", "2019-03-20 01:45:04", "2019-03-20 02:00:01", 
"2019-03-20 02:00:02", "2019-03-20 02:00:03", "2019-03-20 02:45:04", 
"2019-03-20 03:00:01", "2019-03-20 03:00:02", "2019-03-20 03:00:03", 
"2019-03-20 03:45:05", "2019-03-20 04:00:01", "2019-03-20 04:00:02", 
"2019-03-20 04:00:04", "2019-03-20 04:45:05", "2019-03-20 05:00:01", 
"2019-03-20 05:00:02",
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the sample data?  It is hard to help this way.

Comment: Hi, It may help to add some sample data to your question, use dput(head(your_data)), and add the result to the question. This will get you a faster and more accurate reply.

Comment: Small sample data included! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First issue... if you want to explicity set all empty cells as NA you can have a custom function like the following:

```
empty_as_na <- function(x){
  if("factor" %in% class(x)) x <- as.character(x) ## since ifelse wont work with factors
  ifelse(as.character(x)!="", x, NA)
}
```

And then apply this function:

```
dplyr::mutate_all(df, .funs = empty_as_na)
```

where `df` is your data frame.

---

Second issue... for removing duplicate rows, you should look at `dplyr::distinct()`

---

Third issue... I did not get what the issue is... maybe you could clarify?

---

I am sorry, I can't give you a complete working example with the data you provided... but these functions should get you where you want.

**EDIT**

Solution for third issue based on comments...

Probably not the most elegant solution, but again, this is limited due to the not provided reprex.

Let `df` be your data frame, `column_new` your new column, `column_number` the column you mentioned that had numbers or FULL written, and `column_car`the column where the cars are.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    column_new = case_when(
      column_number == "FULL" & column_car == "car_a" ~ 300,
      column_number == "FULL" & column_car == "car_b" ~ 500,
      TRUE ~ column_number
    )
  )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, just tested out the first and second issue there and when I applied the code to the first problem the Error that came up was "Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function" "

Comment: The second problem I tried the dplyr:distinct() and nothing happened it just ran through all the data without removing anything.

Comment: And the Third problem was that some of the cells say FULL, and I would like to put numbers instead of FULL, but FULL for one car park might be 300 spaces and FULL for another might be 500. Just code that I can change the FULL per column. Thanks.

Comment: you should re-check what you are doing with the 1st issue... the function works for me... for the 2nd, if nothing happened is that because you don't have duplicates.. if you want to find duplicates in a specific column you can also do that with distinct, just like that `distinct(column_a)`.. for the third issue see edit